# internet says it is connected but it doesn't work

Tags: wireless, internet, connection

Ok so I am totally new to the ubuntu system but my friend hooked me up with a computer and installed the software. I have no idea what's going on. The internet says it is connected but I can not get on the internet at all. I have restarted it over and over and still nothing. I don't see any errors and the only time it worked was when my friend tested it with ethernet. After that, nada. Please help me. I don't want to end up breaking the thing by either pressing the wrong thing or throwing it against the wall, which I am considering if I can't make it work. Lol. Not really though. But still. I'm getting really infuriated with it.

I am using wireless. Sorry if I wasn't clear earlier.

Comment: Ok, please press "Alt + F2" and write `gnome-terminal`, enter, then type `ping 4.2.2.2`, enter, and edit your post and paste the output. Also, run `ifconfig`, enter, and paste the output here. Are you trying to use wireless or ethernet? Isn't clear on your question.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are using wireless ,for using wireless in ubuntu you must install wireless driver first.
press alt+f2 and type driver and choose hardware driver (additional hardware driver).then active the last one.
cheerz

Comment: Please be more detailed, upload pictures if you must. This answer is vague.